# Can NLog create a new target file if the current file is locked?

Tags: nlog

We are currently using NLog to output to a csv file.  If someone opens that file to view the contents while the application is running, nothing new is added to that file because the file is locked.  Are there any NLog target attributes that would force NLog to output to a new file if the current one is locked?

What would be the effect of adding the fileAttributes output option with a value of "ReadOnly"?

Comment: You can consider to use a cached-timestamp. Then the application will write to a new file at every startup. Ex: `fileName="${basedir}\${date:cached=True:format=yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss}_Log.csv"`

Comment: Are you using Excel? Really lame that all those MS office applications are locking files, even for reading.

Answer (score 0):

If a file is locked, then the file system will reject any writes.

So the best option is there to choose a viewer that won't locks the file. It's not needed when reading.

E.g. Visual Studio Code won't lock the file and even automatisch reloads the file after a change.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution that works for us:

By setting the fileAttributes Output Option to "ReadOnly", this forces a prompt for the user when attempting to open the file with Excel and allows the file to be open in read only mode.